# Binding linux gadget to udc driver

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, usb-drive, usb-device, usb-otg

I want to bind my g_hid gadget to the usb otg port on my board. I Know that using the configFS one can bind the gadget to a UDC driver just by pass the name of the otg port, as explained [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt) 
but if I want to do that (manually) without using the configFS, which filed of which data structure is responsible about that binding process?